# CaptureStackBackTrace(...) Выдаёт неполный стек вызовов на x86

Tags: c++, winapi

А на x64 тот же самый код нормально работает, выдаёт полный стек. В чём может быть проблема? Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

"Frame pointer ommision", естественно, выключено в обоих случаях.

Comment: А код с суффиксом 64 должен работать на 32 битах?

Comment: В данном случае это не важно. Глюки начинаются ещё до того, как доходит до кода с суффиксом 64.

Comment: А на сколько меньше? framesCount = 63?

Comment: под 64 бита люди подумали и сделали так, чтобы стек можно было однозначно развернуть. Под x86 это не всегда возможно. И очень часто функции разворачивания стека "гадают  на кофейной гуще".